# Absolute positioning with drag and drop in the Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, designer

I want make a complex layout, with absolute coordinates, I use RelativeLayout, with left and top margins, but there are a lot of objects, and it is hard to write all that coordinates in the text editor, thus I decided to use Design tab, but it doesn't allow to move second button to an arbitrary position, always snap to an existing objects, I found a solution, at first instead of RelativeLayout wrote AbsoluteLayout, did absolute positioning, and then refacored layout_x and layout_y to layout_marginLeft and layout_marginTop, but I want to know is there an option to turn off snapping in the Design tab when root layout is RelativeLayout
[image: Snap is on]

Comment: "with absolute coordinates" that's a bad idea.

Comment: I know, never did, but now making a card game, and need absolute positioning, it much simple in this case, than struggling with relative parameters, it is working now, no problems, only hard part is put element in the desig editor :)

Comment: just as a heads-up. Games are usually done with a SurfaceView (or one of its sub-classes like GLSurfaceView) and everything is draw directly to the canvas.

Comment: But its simpler for card game or roulette game, to make a custom view, with an XML, then draw that view into the Canvas, and then draw the bitmap on the SurfaceView, I used SurfaceView too, for drawing a Bitmap, but to make a whole card and roulette table in the SurfaceView, programatically, was very hard for me, thats why I choose this solution, Its working now with no problems, with isometric view and touch detection, I only needed to make a layouting process even simplier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do absolute positioning in RelativeLayout. It's not "snapping", it's showing you the actual relative payout.

You can only do absolute positioning in AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, commonly it is a correct answer, I will mark it as solved, I also never did absolute positioning, but now decided to make an exception, because relative layout is more complicated in this case, and I decided to use absolute positioning, with view.draw(Canvas) method, I do layout and measure manually, with specified sizes, draw it into the canvas, and then draw that bitmap in the view, I did so, because I need an isometric view, with matrix transformations, which works well, I only needed to make a layout easy with designer )

Comment: Am I missing absolutelayout as a listed layout or do you need to manually declare this in the code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that still exists, but it's been deprecated since API 3.